# Lecroy model descriptions

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm looking for a Lecroy 9354 on ebay and found that there are a number of different models A, AM, L, CM, etc...

I though this was simple but having searched around for a while I still don't know what the letters describe.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Ebay is almost a forbidden name here. You buy from Ebay and assume all risk. Better to contact Lecroy if possible. Not all descriptors are made public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 second of web search gave me the manual. 10 seconds to find the page

5 minutes to tell you below.

[image] 
[image]
another minute to find the other manual

Comment: With help from @Tony, typically this info can be found in the Appendix of the manuals, search for 'model' or 'signal capture in the appendix. Link to typical manual, [Lecroy 9300](http://cdn.teledynelecroy.com/files/manuals/9300_om_reva.pdf). 'C' seems to mean color dispay model.

Comment: Actually received answer from the source, i.e. LeCroy support: "The models without the A have only BNC inputs, whereas the A-models have already the so called ProBus inputs. These inputs have a command BNC-connection but as well a ProbeBus which enables the supply and control of our Active Probes.
M and L means the size of the Acquistion memory and C was the latest version of the 9354 models which simply all hat [sic] the latest Power PC mainboard plus a floppy drive as standard.". So, "C" is definitely NOT color.